# argparse dealing with strings and spaces in bash commands

Tags: python, string, bash, argparse

I have a bash job that I want to run on the HPC cluster. In my bash script, I am using Job Arrays so I do not write a separate script to each job I want to submit. For efficiency, I have stored all the commands I want to execute (1 command for each job in the array) in a `.txt` file as follows:

```
python mybashtest.py --fname 'Sofia' --lname 'Ghnam'
python mybashtest.py --fname 'Loulou' --lname 'Ghnam'
python mybashtest.py --fname 'Leen' --lname 'hkg02'
python mybashtest.py --fname 'Leen Khaled' --lname 'Gh'
```

I am using python's `argparse` for parsing arguments. Here is my python script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My script')
parser.add_argument('--fname', type=str, default='')
parser.add_argument('--lname', type=str, default='')

parsed_args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(parsed_args.fname + " " + parsed_args.lname)
```

This is the shell script I am using in order to run the job array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH --job-name=all_jobs
#SBATCH --account=hkg02
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --array=1-3

module load python/3
# Print the task id.
echo "My SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: " $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
# here the head -n $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID reads the first n lines 
# from the txt file of job command, the # tail -n 1 takes the last line of those.
# A simple trick to associate the Job array number 
# with the appropriate line number in the txt file of command
srun $(head -n $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID jobstest.txt | tail -n 1)
```

I have 2 problems which are the following:

1. The output of my program is as follows (lets take for example the first job)

   ```
   My SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID:  1
   'Sofia' 'Ghnam'
   ```

   I do not want the `''` to be part of the printed output. I am not sure why they are present;
   Usually I pass any string in `''` because of the fact that a string might have spaces. And when
   that happens, please see the second bullet:
2. In the final job, where the string I am passing had spaced in between `--fname 'Leen Khaled'`, i had the following error

> My SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID:  4
> usage: mybashtest.py [-h] [--fname FNAME] [--lname LNAME]
> mybashtest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Khaled'
> srun: error: onode08: task 0: Exited with exit code 2
> 3. List item

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with slurm. Please confirm that this behavior still occurs when run normally with your interpreter.

Comment: It has to do with the way bash accepts strings with spaces @AryaMcCarthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of trying to solve this, the following is what I did:

1. For solving problem 1, bash takes strings **without spaces** as is, so no need to include them inside double quotes `""` or single quotes `''`
2. For solving problem 2, it turns out that for bash to accept strings with spaces, we have to initialize those strings as variables and then use them appropriately as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH --job-name=all_jobs
#SBATCH --account=hkg02
#SBATCH --nodes=1

var1="Leen Khaled"
module load python/3
python mybashtest.py --fname "${var1}" --lname Gh
```

and this will output:

```
Leen Khaled Gh
```